# behavior different when run outside of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, stack, calling-convention

I was surprised about the behavior of the following code:

```
if(RegQueryValueEx(....)!=ERROR_SUCCESS){
...
}
```

when it was run from visual studio it didn't enter this if block, because the key did exist. when ran outside of the visual studio environment it evaluated true and hence entered the block, even though the queried key existed. After some testing i found out that when i first save it to a variable it runs always fine. With the following code:

```
HKEY hSoftwareKey,hAppKey;
DWORD dwLength;
int iStatus=1;
char szBuffer[MAX_PATH];
if(iStatus&&RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software",&hSoftwareKey)!=ERROR_SUCCESS)
    iStatus = 0;
if(iStatus&&RegCreateKeyA(hSoftwareKey,"Amine",&hAppKey)!=ERROR_SUCCESS){
    iStatus = 0;
}

ZeroMemory(szBuffer,MAX_PATH);
LONG lRet;
lRet = RegQueryValueExA(hAppKey,"One",0,0,reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(szBuffer),&dwLength);
```

Does this bevavior have anything to do with the __stdcall/WINAPI calling convention? If so could somebody please explain why

Comment: Are you executing this with the same use access elevation in both cases ? what lRet are you getting

Comment: same elevation. lRet is ERROR_SUCCESS. The funny thing is i have to first store the return value but i can't compare it directly in the if block

Comment: Are you running the same (debug) build exe from within and outside Visual Studio? Please edit the question and give all the parameters to the `RegQueryValueEx()` call

Comment: its the exact same file. sure Ill put in the parameters

Comment: @thebaconing please don't fix the code in the question, otherwise the answer does not make sense and future readers will not be able to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Steve sure thing, I haven't thought about it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `dwLength` to `MAX_PATH` before calling RegQueryValueEx(), otherwise it's value is undefined.

from [MSDN RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx):

> lpcbData is a pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. When the function returns, this variable contains the size of the data copied to lpData

Comment: well you're right(I just read the article myself), but even though i didn't do it it still works. thats probably because this parameter is optional

Comment: it's optional only when `lpData` is NULL

Comment: Indeed the weird return behavior was caused by not initializing dwLength. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `dwLength` was being initialized to `0xCCCCCCCC` under Visual Studio, but something random when being run outside.  See https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Debugging/Debugging_on_MS_Windows#Memory_Values